# How do I change the css for a future element being made in a to do list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, phonegap

For my final project we're making a to do list with the phonegap plugins system. For extra credit, the user should be able to pick the colors that they want for the priority of the set task (low, medium, high) The defaults are set in the css (in classes named `".low" ".med" ".high"`) and I have it set up already to change the color of the task if it is already in the table.

Although this first part works, the second issue is that tasks added later are still given the default color rather than the user chosen one. I'm not sure how to change the background color for all present and future elements of the given priority.

Priority color to change:

```html
<select id='colorChange`' onchange="colorSelected();">
    <option value='Low' selected>Pick Priority Colors</option>
    <option value='Low'>Low</option>
    <option value='Med'>Med</option> 
    <option value='High'>High</option>
</select>
```

Color chooser:

```html
    <input id="color" type="color">
```

Javascript when new task is added:

```js
if (priority == "Low")
    var style = "low";
else if (priority == "Med")
    var style = "med";
else
    var style = "high";

table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`
    <tr><td class="tg-rykj ${style}"><input type="radio" class="done"></td>
    <td class="tg-cly1 name ${style}">${txt}</td>
    <td class="dates ${style}">${date}</td>
    <td class="tg-cly1 ${style}">${priority}</td>
    <td class="tg-cly1 ${style}">${category}</td>
    <td>
        <img id="delete" src="img/delete.png" 
        onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none'; 
        updateTable();">
    </td>
    </tr>`);
```

JS to change elements already in table:

```js
function colorSelected () {
        var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
        var select = document.getElementById('colorChange').value;
        if (select == "Low")
            var style = document.getElementsByClassName('low');
        else if (select == "Med")
            var style = document.getElementsByClassName('med');
        else
            var style = document.getElementsByClassName('high');
        for(var i = 0; i < style.length; i++){
            style[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
}
```

Images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new stylesheet by adding a `style` tag to the document head. Then you can add new rules to that stylesheet, always adding at the end to make sure that the new rule gets priority over previous rules. For example,

```
// declare the styleSheet as a global so that a new one
// is not created every time addColor is called
let styleSheet;

function addColor(className, color) {
  // create stylesheet, if not already created
  if (!styleSheet) {
    const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
    styleSheet = styleElement.sheet;
  }

  // insert style rule at the end of the stylesheet,
  // overriding existing rules on same selector
  styleSheet.insertRule(
    `.${className} { color: ${color} }`,
    styleSheet.cssRules.length
  );
}

// callback for event listener, grabs the correct values
// and calls the `addColor` function with them
function colorSelected() {
  const color = document.getElementById('color').value;
  const selected = document.getElementById('colorChange').value;
  addColor(selected.toLowerCase(), color);
}
```

`CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()` takes two parameters: a string representing the rule you want to add, and an index at which to add it. Since you want it to be at the end of the stylesheet, you use the `cssRules.length` property to determine where the last index would be. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) for more info.

Comment: At the top of the function first choose the color by adding click function document.getElementById("color").click();

Comment: @LDS I'm not sure what the `click` would be for, but I did rewrite the code so that it had the full functionality to replace the `colorSelected()` function provided in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Just I am taking a div and apply your code with a little bit change and it works fine

```html
<html>

<head>
<style>
.Low{background-color: coral}
.Med{background-color: red}
.Heigh{background-color: green}
</style>
<script>
alert("test");
function colorSelected() {
 
        var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
 alert(color);
        var select = document.getElementById('colorChange').value;
        if (select == "Low")
            var style = document.getElementsByClassName('low');
        else if (select == "Med")
 
            var style = document.getElementsByClassName('med');
        else
            var style = document.getElementsByClassName('high');
        for(var i = 0; i < style.length; i++){
            style[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id='colorChange' onChange="return colorSelected();">
    <option value='Low' selected>Pick Priority Colors</option>
    <option value='Low'>Low</option>
    <option value='Med'>Med</option> 
    <option value='High'>High</option>
</select>
<div class = "Low">
<div style="width:500px;height:300px;">
</div>
</div>
<div class = "Med">
<div style="width:500px;height:300px;">
</div>
</div>
<br>
 <input id="color" type="color" />


</body>
</hrml>
```